# WPF DVC Chart axis labeling

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have created a DVC:Chart as shown below in my code, how do i add x-axis and y-axis labels to the chart?

```
    <DVC:Chart Name="callLogs" 
       Background="SteelBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Calls per Hour" 
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            </DVC:ColumnSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to figure it out:

```
    <DVC:Chart Name="callLogs" 
       Background="SteelBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DVC:Chart.Axes>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Ammount of calls"/>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="Time (Hours)"/>
        </DVC:Chart.Axes>
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Calls per Hour" 
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            </DVC:ColumnSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

However, its labeling my x-axis for me, don't know how to customize it, so i will post the new solution when i figure it out.